# How do you use the Synaptic packege manager for downloading packages?

Tags: synaptic

I new to Ubuntu, and have just installed Synaptic. I want to Know how to use it for downloading packages and and software.Please help.

Comment: Do you mean installing or precisely just downloading?

Comment: What's the difference between installing and downloading?

Comment: Well, it seems to me you were looking for installing packages. The target is to run those tools in your machine. Using Synaptic, some users may look to download only those packages without installing them to be used later or to be installed in other machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Synaptic Package Manager** is used for installing debian packages  and not for downloading source code of a particular package.To install a package through synaptic follow the below steps.

- Open [synaptic package manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) from Dash.
- Search for the package you have to install.
- After finding it,right click on it and select **Mark for installation**.And select **Apply**.
- Package will be installed successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Beginning with Synaptic Package Manager:

Since you've just installed it, from the menu select *Settings -> Repositories* and under *Ubuntu Software* select the repositories like *main, universe, restricted* and others and close the window.

[image: snap0a]

Then click *Reload* to reload the package list; after the reload is complete you can search for the packages and install them.

#### To install a package:

In the synaptic package manager right click the package you want to install and select **Mark for Installation** then click **Apply**.

[image: snap1]

---

You can use *Search*, *Quick filter* to look for the packages with key words. Click the **Sections** tab to get the categorized package listing, select any category you want and you can not only get a list of applications but descriptions and more.

#### References:

- [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/)
- [Synaptic Package Manager: How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)