# unable to locate package fpc

Tags: installation, software-installation

When I try to install any package through the command line, I get an error. Can anyone help me on this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
E: Unable to locate package fpc
```

and here's the snapshot.
[image: snap1]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Why do you think the package "fpc" should exist? Also, please give us the complete command you issued. Please add the information to your question by editing it.

Comment: @MadMike you can find out if a package exists at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search

Answer (score 1):

To install `fpc` you should have the *Universe* repository enabled. From command line, you can do this and then install the application as shown below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fpc
```

Source [How do I enable the “Universe” repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line)

[Synaptic Package Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407369/how-do-you-use-the-synaptic-packege-manager-for-downloading-packages/407372#407372) is a good graphical package manager, if you might want to give it a try!